# Copy all EXIF information from one jpg to another jpg in R

Tags: r, exiftool

I read a jpg image into R as well as all of its EXIF metadata.
Then I do some manipulation to the image and write the output as jpg.
How could I copy all EXIF information to the new jpg file?
(I understand I will need to modify only few tags).
I find very useful information on how to read the EXIF metadata in R
(eg, packages Thermimage or exiftoolr), but not on writing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `exiftoolr` package allows you to call `exif_call()` to run any command that the underlying `exiftool` can do. Examples are included here: https://exiftool.org/examples.html. So if you wanted to run the following command in R you would translate

```
exiftool -artist="Phil Harvey" -copyright="2011 Phil Harvey" a.jpg
```

into

```
exiftoolr::exif_call(args=c(
   '-artist="Phil Harvey"', 
   '-copyright="2011 Phil Harvey"'
 ), 
 path="a.jpg")
```

Comment: Based on this answer, in order to copy the metadata, I would suggest something along these lines 
`exiftoolr::exif_call(args=c(
   '-TagsFromFile', 
   'path/to/source.jpg',
   '-All:All'
 ), 
 path="a.jpg")`

Comment: @MrFlick: thanks, but the problem is that there are many tags to copy.

Comment: @StarGeek: Yes, this would be the way. 1st I copy all tags and then modify the few that have to be modified.

Comment: Using `-All:All` will copy nearly every tag in the file that exiftool can copy but there are some tags, such as ICC_Profiles that are marked as unsafe to copy because they can affect how the image is displayed.  If you wish to copy that, you would add another line with `-ColorSpaceTags`